# My cPanel login is being redirected. How can I resolve this?

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, authentication

I'm trying to get to cPanel to manage my website. When I type `www.mydomain.com:2082` into the browser window, the request seems to be redirected. I made a screen-cast so I could slow down the changes in the address bar.

First it seems to go to

```
http://www.mydomain.com:2082/login
```

then

```
http://www.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/login.cgi
```

At this point, a screen briefly appears which says 'Login attempt failed'
and then the address is redirected to `https://this22.thishost.com:2083/`, which is no relation to my site at all.

This looks to me like there has been an attack on the system and the login.cgi file is compromised. Any suggestions on how to analyze this further? or fix it? Of course my 'free hosting' isn't any help at all.

Comment: Have you gone to yourdomain.com/cpanel

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an attack.

Someone must have changed the script files. These things most often happen with free hosting. You need to talk to your support team if possible and see if they can sort this one out.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question with "shared-hosting", you need to contact your hosting-provider about this issue. You also wrote that you are using a free hoster, it is possible that their servers has been attacked.

Furthermore you should check if your home-computer's host file is clean of any redirection of your server's IP adress or your domain name. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29 for more info about the host file.